# fql stream table: retrieve all the posts of a specific user containing tags

Tags: stream, tags, facebook-fql

I have to write an FQL query to retrieve all the posts of a specific user which contain tags. I've tried with:

```sql
SELECT post_id, source_id, target_id, actor_id, message
FROM stream
WHERE
    source_id = [tagPublisherId]
    AND actor_id = [tagPublisherId]
    AND tagged_ids != NULL
```

but it doesn't work because "NULL is not a member of the stream table". How can I check for a not empty array type in a FQL query?

Comment: Try using just `AND tagged_ids` – FQL treats an “empty” value, 0 and NULL as false and everything else as true.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your reply. It seems to work but it retrieves only posts written at most a week ago. I've also tried  with     "created_time >= [aYearAgo] LIMIT 100".